# Powershell: Conditionally changing objects in the pipeline

Tags: powershell

I'm converting a CSV to SQL inserts and there's a null-able text column which I need to quote in case it is not NULL. I would write something like the following for the conversion:

```
Import-Csv data.csv | foreach { "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COL1,COL2) VALUES ($($_.COL1),$($_.COL2));" >> inserts.sql }
```

But I can't figure out how to add an additional tier into the pipeline to look if COL2 is not equal to 'NULL' and to quote it in such cases. How do I achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code block of the `foreach-object` cmdlet you can have multiple statements, something like:

```
Import-Csv data.csv | 
foreach {
  if ($_.COL1 -ne $null) {
    $c1 = "'$($_.COL1)'"
  } else {
    $c1 = $_.COL1
  }
  "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COL1,COL2) VALUES ($c1,$($_.COL2));" >> inserts.sql
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a solution of course, but I wonder if there's a less verbose way of doing this, maybe something similar to how you can do filtering.

Comment: PSCX () providers some helpers that work like a conditional operator which would certainly help in this case. http://pscx.codeplex.com/